Exact sequence of finitely generated free modules, $\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i rk(F_i)=0$
This question is actually the exercise 10.33 in Rotman Advanced abstract algebra: Let $0\to F_N\to F_{N-1}\to  \cdots \to F_0\to 0$ be an exact sequence of finitely generated free k-modules, where k is a commutative ring (contains a unit). Prove that $\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i rank(F_i)=0$.
I have tried to prove it by induction, where I decompose the exact sequence into two shorter exact sequences. But I can't find a right way to decompose it so that I maintain my assumption: each position is an free modules. I actually use kernel and image, which are not free generally I believe.
Maybe there is something I lost with the condition: finitely generated or it isn't the right way to do it. Can anyone help me with that?
I found some related questions on groups or vector spaces, but I still could not figure it out.

Is it ok to prove only the case when $k$ contains a unit? Not sure if this assumption is really required but I can give a simple proof in this case.

@Matsmir  Actually, it’s assumed in this book that
$k$ always contains a unit. Apologies for overlooking that this might not be a common assumption. Could you please share your proof for the case when $k$ contains a unit?

We need a lemma. Everywhere we assume that $k$ and all $k$-modules are unital.
Lemma. Assume that $0 \rightarrow F_n \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow F_0 \rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence of flat $k$-modules. Then for any $k$-module $M$ the sequence $0 \rightarrow F_n \otimes M \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow F_0 \otimes M \rightarrow 0$ is exact.
Proof. The case $n \le 2$ is empty, $n = 3$ is straightforward from the definition of flat modules. We prove by induction and assume $n > 3$. We decompose the sequence into $0 \rightarrow F_n \rightarrow F_{n-1} \rightarrow\dots \rightarrow  F_2 \rightarrow Z \rightarrow 0$ and $0 \rightarrow Z \rightarrow F_{1} \rightarrow F_0 \rightarrow 0$. Clearly, $Z$ is flat since $F_1$ and $F_0$ are flat. After tensoring with $M$ we obtain from the induction hypothesis that $0 \rightarrow F_n \otimes M \rightarrow F_{n-1} \otimes M \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow  F_2 \otimes M \rightarrow Z \otimes M \rightarrow 0$ and $0 \rightarrow Z \otimes M \rightarrow F_{1} \otimes M \rightarrow F_0 \otimes M \rightarrow 0$ are exact. The proof finishes by observing that these two sequences combine into the sequence $0 \rightarrow F_n \otimes M \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow F_0 \otimes M \rightarrow 0$, so it is exact. $\blacksquare$
Now I shall use the following statement, which is the problem in question in the case of a field $k$. For this case your attempt proof works perfectly.
Lemma. Assume that $k$ is a field and $0 \rightarrow F_n \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow F_0 \rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence of finite-dimensional vector spaces over $k$. Then $\sum (-1)^m \dim F_m = 0$. $\blacksquare$
Finally, we are ready to prove the general case.
Proposition. Assume that $0 \rightarrow F_n \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow F_0 \rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence of free finitely-generated $k$-modules. Then $\sum (-1)^m \mathrm{rank} F_m = 0$.
Proof. Consider arbitrary maximal ideal $I \subset k$ and let $K = k/I$ be the quotient (which is a field). From the first lemma we obtain that the sequence $0 \rightarrow F_n \otimes K \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow F_0 \otimes K \rightarrow 0$ is exact. Note that this sequence consists of finite-dimensional vector spaces over $K$ and morphisms are linear operators. Thus, $\sum (-1)^m \dim (F_m \otimes K) = 0$. Finally, $\dim (F_m \otimes K) = \mathrm{rank} F_m$. $\blacksquare$

Thanks for your answer! I have a question about the last part: why is $dim(F_m\otimes K) = rank(F_M)$?
I've just started learning and am not very familiar with tensor products and flatness. Could you provide some clarification?

We can decompose $F_m = k \oplus k \oplus \dots \oplus k$ where $\mathrm{rank} F_m$ is the number of direct summands. Since tensor product is distributive over direct sum we obtain $F_m \otimes K = (k \otimes K) \oplus \dots \oplus (k \otimes K)$. Finally, $k \otimes K \sim K$, since $k$ is the neutral element with respect to tensor product. So, $F_m \otimes K = K \oplus \dots \oplus K$, where the number of direct summands on the one hand is $\dim (F_m \otimes K)$ and on the other hand $\mathrm{rank} F_m$.
